# How to keep track of an activity in order to restart it later

Tags: android, android-activity, history

I have an activity that requires a number of actions to be done before it can perform its task. in the onResume() method of that activity a check is done to determine if the requirements are met, if not a chain of activities will be activated to complete the requirements. what would be the best approach to keep record of the original activity in order to get back to it after the requirements have been gathered.

My solution was to pass the original activity's intent contents through the activities call chain in order to be able to restart the original activity again once all the requirements are gathered but i feel that this is not the optimal solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hope this makes sense, I'm trying to understand your requirements as best I can since you don't actually say what the application does.

I'd have the base activity check the prerequisites, then fire off the first relevant secondary activity with `startActivityForResult`. I'd have the secondary activity use `setResult(RESULT_OK)`/`finish()` which would bring control back to the base activity. I'd have the base activity check the prerequisites anew each time rather than trying to remember what had supposedly been completed. The shared preferences could be used to store when prerequisites were completed by the secondary tasks if necessary.

Comment: Hey Jim, the thing is that chain of call will probably be more than two activities in a row and am afraid that this might become messy. BTW the base activity is meant to sell a service and if the user doesn't have his credit card information set he'd have to go through the process of adding his credit card info and selecting from different payment options. but thank you very much for the suggestion ill try it and see how it goes.

Comment: thanks Jim i took your advice but i used my own constant rather than using RESULT_OK because i needed to determine the route of chain calls depending on the value returned